# Dynamically define and get Models in Waterline

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I was wondering if it's possible in Waterline to define models or get a model by name like in [Node-ORM2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2).

Defining:

```
var Person = db.define("person", {
    name      : String,
    surname   : String,
    age       : Number, // FLOAT
    male      : Boolean,
    continent : [ "Europe", "America", "Asia", "Africa", "Australia", "Antartica" ], // ENUM type
    photo     : Buffer, // BLOB/BINARY
    data      : Object // JSON encoded
}, {
    methods: {
        fullName: function () {
            return this.name + ' ' + this.surname;
        }
    },
    validations: {
        age: orm.enforce.ranges.number(18, undefined, "under-age")
    }
});
```

Getting:

```
var MyPersonModel = db.models["person"];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sails exposes your models on the `sails.models` object, so the following will work:

```
var MyPersonModel = sails.models['person'];
```

If you want to access your model off of the global object:

```
var MyPersonModel = global['Person'];
```

The sails object is also available as a property of the http request object, so in any route, you can do:

```
var MyPersonModel = req._sails.models['person'];
```

In fact, if you want to exclusively access models via `sails.models` or `req._sails.models` and you don't want sails to export your models as properties of the global object, you can set the configuration `globals.models = false`.

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate-backend/blob/master/templates/config/globals.js#L53-62

Comment: Good stuff, thanks. Any method for defining new models?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I doubt it.  The code that loads modules is spread out over a few files: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/orm/load-user-modules.js,  https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/moduleloader/index.js#L277, https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/orm/normalize-model.js, and https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/orm/build-orm.js#L61

Comment: Sails is `require`ing all the files in the models directory, then normalizing / mucking with the definition, then subclassing waterline.Collection using the normalized definition, and finally instantiating the Collection.  The instance is the value you see as sails.models['person']