# How can you drop an attribute from the database in Sails/Waterline

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

*(EDITED to clarify that I want to delete/drop an attribute from the database when it is deleted from an object)*

I have a small Sails application with a schema-less model that allows attributes to be added and saved to the database (currently just the `sails-disk` file system adaptor for testing purposes).

The problem I am having is that I can't find a way to permanently delete attributes from the database.

When I delete an attribute on an object which is a model instance I also want the attribute dropped from the database. This will be useful when I move to an object database like MongoDB and have objects with dynamically created attributes.

Deleting an attribute using `delete object[attributeName]` and then saving with the instance method `object.save()` does not work, the deleted attributes still remain.

For example if I have this object:

```
{
  "name": "Chair",
  "colour": "white"
}
```

Let's say I want to remove the `colour` attribute to replace it with a `material` attribute like this:

```
{
  "name": "Chair",
  "material": "pine"
}
```

After updating the object in the database the new `material` attribute is added, but the deleted `colour` attribute is not removed.
So the end result in the database will be this:

```
{
  "name": "Chair",
  "colour": "white",
  "material": "pine"
}
```

So this is not the outcome I am after.

Is there a way to permanently delete/drop attributes from an object in the database using Sails/Waterline?

Comment: This is relative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747808/dynamically-define-and-get-models-in-waterline but i think what you're trying to do is not possible however I do vaguely remember seeing something about this being possible in the v1 docs but cannot find it now so don't trust my words on that. I also think that it would be better for you to revise your model so that each of the items has various associated options. See here: http://0.12.sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/many-to-many

Comment: Can see here too: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1160

Comment: Thanks @CraigvanTonder, unfortunately your links have not provided any additional clues. Perhaps you are right, what I am hoping for is not possible. :(

Comment: I edited the original question to clarify the intent - it might have been ambiguous before...

Comment: It seems that I may have gone off on a tangent in thinking that you were trying to modify a models attribute value, this is currently problematic as I was trying to point out. So okay, You have a JSON object, you have to save this in sails-disk? So then work with Sails and use a model which has an attribute value that contains JSON. See here for more on this: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes - So then you will be able to use the waterline functionality (http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models) to create / read / update / delete?

Comment: @CraigvanTonder, i think you were on the right track before, when i delete an attribute on an object which is a model instance i also want the attribute dropped from the database. This will be useful when i move to an object database like mongodb and have objects with dynamically created attributes. I'll clarify my question again... :)

Answer (score 2):

I am sure it is too late for this but I had the same issue. What I did was just create a new object and delete the old one. If you want to do this programatically, just compare the key of the current object and the old one. The problem with this is that you must also update all related models (and collections) with the new id.

Answer (score 1):

You can't by default "unset" an attribute because structured SQL databases do not work that way. You can set the attribute to NULL is the most you can do with straight SailsJS. In a structured DB like MySql, MSSQL, Oracle, PGSQL when you do not supply an attribute the DB will insert a default value (NULL or other prescribed value by the schema definition) or throw an error at you.

For NoSQL DB like Mongo they do have an "unset" option which Sails does not support out of the box. In Sails you would have to do a native query using sails.model["name"].getDatastore().manager then run the native Mongo update query using $unset to remove the attribute.

```
const db = sails.model["products"].getDatastore().manager;
await db.collection("products").update(
       { sku: "unknown" },
       { $unset: { quantity: "", instock: "" } });
```

** updateMany can also be used the same way for multiple records at the same time.

ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/

Otherwise document replacement (cringe) is the only other alternative as stated before.